# How to debug ActiveMQ client?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm a fairly new user of ActiveMQ and I'm looking for a way to get detailed debug information on the client side of a queue connection.  My problem is this: I have a server that is sending a message through a queue to a client.  Using the admin web page associated with the broker, I can verify the following: the queue was created, there is a consumer associated with the queue, the message has been enqueued, the message has been dispatched, the dispatched queue size is 1, the message has not been dequeued.  This setup was working yesterday but mysteriously stopped working today even though I did a restart of the activemq service.  The log file at /var/log/activemq.log does not contain any useful information.

At this point I'm stumped; I'm assuming that there is some sort of problem with the configuration, but it hasn't changed since yesterday.  Does anybody have a suggestion about what my next step should be?

Answer (score 4):

Turn on debug (or even trace) logging in the broker first of all in conf/log4j.properties.

log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=DEBUG

restart the broker and re-run your scenario. The logging will hopefully provide you with some information. 
Jconsole is also a useful tool to monitor the running broker.

Does your client use any message filters?

Comment: No message filters, and I can't really control the broker configuration because I'm not root (useful info though).  Is there any way to get low level info on the client side about whether it has received bytes that it's waiting to deliver?

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable remote debugging and then connect with an IDE.
To start remote debugging execute

`$ ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG=true bin/activemq`

and then start a remote debugger to connect to port 5005